# Как интегрируется платежная система в Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Как интегрируется платежная система в Flutter? Есть пакеты для PayPal, Razor. Нужно создавать собственный пакет? Если можно подробно как действовать.

Comment: Для начала напишите какая платежная система вам нужна!

Comment: [sdkGithub](https://github.com/PaycomUZ/AndroidSDK/) для мобильной интеграции. [сайт](https://help.paycom.uz/ru/protokol-subscribe-api). Это система только для внутреннего использования.

Comment: для этой платежной системы ничего нет. И плагин полноценный не напишешь, так как нет SDK под iOS. Возможно у них есть API через который можно делать оплату. Посмотрите на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Не возможно ответить конкретно на ваш вопрос. Какую платежную систему вы хотите использовать? Если для вашей платежной системы еще не написан пакет, то вы можете написать его [сами](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels). Так же вы можете использовать webview, для того чтобы отобразить платежную страницу.

Flutter активно развивается. Поэтому скоро появятся пакеты для всех платежных систем. Я бы рекомендовал использовать платежную систему, у которой уже есть пакет для flutter. Например [stripe_payment](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment)